# "undefined reference to " when calling ffmpeg1.2.1 in Cplusplus using ANDROID NDK

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk, ffmpeg, static-linking

when i call ffmpeg1.2.1 lib in Cplusplus wrapper with android NDK,  some symbols cannot be linked ,the errors occur when linking as follows. but the other symbols can be linked,why? how to correct the mistake ?

```
SharedLibrary  : libplayer.so
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:124: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_string(char*, int, AVCodecContext*, int)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:124: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_string(char*, int, AVCodecContext*, int)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:124: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_string(char*, int, AVCodecContext*, int)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:144: error: undefined reference to 'av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/cores/player/Demuxers/DemuxFFmpeg.cpp:248: error: undefined reference to 'av_log_set_callback(void (*)(void*,mytestt*,     std::__va_list))'
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:144: error: undefined reference to 'av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/cores/player/Demuxers/DemuxFFmpeg.cpp:701: error: undefined reference to 'av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/cores/player/Demuxers/DemuxFFmpeg.cpp:798: error: undefined reference to 'av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
/home/mytest/player/jni/lib/DllAvCodec.h:108: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_find_decoder(AVCodecID)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
DEFINES += \
           -DTARGET_POSIX \
           -DTARGET_LINUX \
           -D_LINUX \
           -DTARGET_ANDROID \
           -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS 

######################################
#build ffmpeg prebuilt lib
######################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libavcodec.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libavfilter.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libavformat.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libavutil.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libpostproc  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libpostproc.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libswresample  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=lib/lib/libswresample.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/lib/libswscale.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


######################################
#build lib
######################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= player
base := $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ... #ignore


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/include \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/cores/dvdplayer \

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Wall -fexceptions $(DEFINES)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libavfilter  \
                          libavutil libpostproc libswscale libswresample 

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L../jni/lib/lib  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

the DllAvcodec.h is:

```
#pragma once


#include "DllAvUtil.h"
#include "utils/log.h"
#define USE_EXTERNAL_FFMPEG  1

extern "C" {
  #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_MICRO >= 100
  #define LIBAVCODEC_FROM_FFMPEG
#else
  #define LIBAVCODEC_FROM_LIBAV
#endif

#include "threads/SingleLock.h"

class DllAvCodecInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~DllAvCodecInterface() {}
  virtual void avcodec_register_all(void)=0;
  virtual void avcodec_flush_buffers(AVCodecContext *avctx)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_open2_dont_call(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVCodec *codec, AVDictionary **options)=0;
  virtual AVCodec *avcodec_find_decoder(enum CodecID id)=0;
  virtual AVCodec *avcodec_find_encoder(enum CodecID id)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_close_dont_call(AVCodecContext *avctx)=0;
  virtual AVFrame *avcodec_alloc_frame(void)=0;
  virtual int avpicture_fill(AVPicture *picture, uint8_t *ptr, PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture, int *got_picture_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame, int *got_frame_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_decode_subtitle2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVSubtitle *sub, int *got_sub_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt)=0;
  ///virtual int avcodec_encode_audio(AVCodecContext *avctx, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, const short *samples)=0;
  ///virtual int avcodec_encode_audio2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt, const AVFrame *frame, int *got_packet_ptr)=0;
  virtual int avpicture_get_size(PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)=0;
  virtual AVCodecContext *avcodec_alloc_context3(AVCodec *codec)=0;
  virtual void avcodec_string(char *buf, int buf_size, AVCodecContext *enc, int encode)=0;
  virtual void avcodec_get_context_defaults3(AVCodecContext *s, AVCodec *codec)=0;
  virtual AVCodecParserContext *av_parser_init(int codec_id)=0;
  virtual int av_parser_parse2(AVCodecParserContext *s,AVCodecContext *avctx, uint8_t **poutbuf, int *poutbuf_size,
                    const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size,
                    int64_t pts, int64_t dts, int64_t pos)=0;
  virtual void av_parser_close(AVCodecParserContext *s)=0;
  virtual AVBitStreamFilterContext *av_bitstream_filter_init(const char *name)=0;
  virtual int av_bitstream_filter_filter(AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc,
    AVCodecContext *avctx, const char *args,
    uint8_t **poutbuf, int *poutbuf_size,
    const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, int keyframe) =0;
  virtual void av_bitstream_filter_close(AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc) =0;
  virtual void avpicture_free(AVPicture *picture)=0;
  virtual void av_free_packet(AVPacket *pkt)=0;
  virtual int avpicture_alloc(AVPicture *picture, PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)=0;
  virtual enum PixelFormat avcodec_default_get_format(struct AVCodecContext *s, const enum PixelFormat *fmt)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_default_get_buffer(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *pic)=0;
  virtual void avcodec_default_release_buffer(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *pic)=0;
  virtual AVCodec *av_codec_next(AVCodec *c)=0;
  virtual int av_dup_packet(AVPacket *pkt)=0;
  virtual void av_init_packet(AVPacket *pkt)=0;
  virtual int avcodec_fill_audio_frame(AVFrame *frame, int nb_channels, enum AVSampleFormat sample_fmt, const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, int align) = 0;
  virtual void avcodec_free_frame(AVFrame **frame)=0;
};


// Use direct layer
class DllAvCodec : public DllAvCodecInterface
{
public:
  static CCriticalSection m_critSection;

  virtual ~DllAvCodec() {}
  virtual void avcodec_register_all()
  {
    CSingleLock lock(DllAvCodec::m_critSection);
    ::avcodec_register_all();
  }
  virtual void avcodec_flush_buffers(AVCodecContext *avctx) { ::avcodec_flush_buffers(avctx); }
  virtual int avcodec_open2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVCodec *codec, AVDictionary **options)
  {
    CSingleLock lock(DllAvCodec::m_critSection);
    return ::avcodec_open2(avctx, codec, options);
  }
  virtual int avcodec_open2_dont_call(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVCodec *codec, AVDictionary **options) { *(volatile int *)0x0 = 0; return 0; }
  virtual int avcodec_close_dont_call(AVCodecContext *avctx) { *(volatile int *)0x0 = 0; return 0; }
  virtual AVCodec *avcodec_find_decoder(enum CodecID id) { return ::avcodec_find_decoder(id); }
  virtual AVCodec *avcodec_find_encoder(enum CodecID id) { return ::avcodec_find_encoder(id); }
  virtual int avcodec_close(AVCodecContext *avctx)
  {
    CSingleLock lock(DllAvCodec::m_critSection);
    return ::avcodec_close(avctx);
  }
  virtual AVFrame *avcodec_alloc_frame() { return ::avcodec_alloc_frame(); }
  virtual int avpicture_fill(AVPicture *picture, uint8_t *ptr, PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height) { return ::avpicture_fill(picture, ptr, pix_fmt, width, height); }
  virtual int avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *picture, int *got_picture_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt) { return ::avcodec_decode_video2(avctx, picture, got_picture_ptr, avpkt); }
  virtual int avcodec_decode_audio4(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *frame, int *got_frame_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt) { return ::avcodec_decode_audio4(avctx, frame, got_frame_ptr, avpkt); }
  virtual int avcodec_decode_subtitle2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVSubtitle *sub, int *got_sub_ptr, AVPacket *avpkt) { return ::avcodec_decode_subtitle2(avctx, sub, got_sub_ptr, avpkt); }
  ///virtual int avcodec_encode_audio(AVCodecContext *avctx, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, const short *samples) { return ::avcodec_encode_audio(avctx, buf, buf_size, samples); }
  ///virtual int avcodec_encode_audio2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVPacket *avpkt, const AVFrame *frame, int *got_packet_ptr) { return ::avcodec_encode_audio2(avctx, avpkt, frame, got_packet_ptr); }
  virtual int avpicture_get_size(PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height) { return ::avpicture_get_size(pix_fmt, width, height); }
  virtual AVCodecContext *avcodec_alloc_context3(AVCodec *codec) { return ::avcodec_alloc_context3(codec); }
  virtual void avcodec_string(char *buf, int buf_size, AVCodecContext *enc, int encode) { ::avcodec_string(buf, buf_size, enc, encode); }
  virtual void avcodec_get_context_defaults3(AVCodecContext *s, AVCodec *codec) { ::avcodec_get_context_defaults3(s, codec); }

  virtual AVCodecParserContext *av_parser_init(int codec_id) { return ::av_parser_init(codec_id); }
  virtual int av_parser_parse2(AVCodecParserContext *s,AVCodecContext *avctx, uint8_t **poutbuf, int *poutbuf_size,
                    const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size,
                    int64_t pts, int64_t dts, int64_t pos)
  {
    return ::av_parser_parse2(s, avctx, poutbuf, poutbuf_size, buf, buf_size, pts, dts, pos);
  }
  virtual void av_parser_close(AVCodecParserContext *s) { ::av_parser_close(s); }

  virtual AVBitStreamFilterContext *av_bitstream_filter_init(const char *name) { return ::av_bitstream_filter_init(name); }
  virtual int av_bitstream_filter_filter(AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc,
    AVCodecContext *avctx, const char *args,
    uint8_t **poutbuf, int *poutbuf_size,
    const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, int keyframe) { return ::av_bitstream_filter_filter(bsfc, avctx, args, poutbuf, poutbuf_size, buf, buf_size, keyframe); }
  virtual void av_bitstream_filter_close(AVBitStreamFilterContext *bsfc) { ::av_bitstream_filter_close(bsfc); }

  virtual void avpicture_free(AVPicture *picture) { ::avpicture_free(picture); }
  virtual void av_free_packet(AVPacket *pkt) { ::av_free_packet(pkt); }
  virtual int avpicture_alloc(AVPicture *picture, PixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height) { return ::avpicture_alloc(picture, pix_fmt, width, height); }
  virtual int avcodec_default_get_buffer(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *pic) { return ::avcodec_default_get_buffer(s, pic); }
  virtual void avcodec_default_release_buffer(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *pic) { ::avcodec_default_release_buffer(s, pic); }
  virtual enum PixelFormat avcodec_default_get_format(struct AVCodecContext *s, const enum PixelFormat *fmt) { return ::avcodec_default_get_format(s, fmt); }
  virtual AVCodec *av_codec_next(AVCodec *c) { return ::av_codec_next(c); }

  virtual int av_dup_packet(AVPacket *pkt) { return ::av_dup_packet(pkt); }
  virtual void av_init_packet(AVPacket *pkt) { return ::av_init_packet(pkt); }
  virtual int avcodec_fill_audio_frame(AVFrame *frame, int nb_channels, enum AVSampleFormat sample_fmt, const uint8_t *buf, int buf_size, int align) { return ::avcodec_fill_audio_frame(frame, nb_channels, sample_fmt, buf, buf_size, align); }
  virtual void avcodec_free_frame(AVFrame **frame) { return ::avcodec_free_frame(frame); };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C" {
```

should include your class `DllAvCodecInterface`, like this:

```
extern "C" { 
class DllAvCodecInterface
{
    ...
};

class DllAvCodec : public DllAvCodecInterface
{
    ...
}

}  // extern "C"
```